# Which KEY_ macro in Linux input.h matches the menu key?

Tags: linux, keyboard-events, uinput

I want to use uinput to emulate pressing the menu key just next to the right Alt key. I tried KEY_MENU and KEY_CONTEXT_MENU, but neither of them worked. The key in Win32 API is VK_APPS.

Comment: Are you on some X11 environment (e.g. a Linux desktop)? If yes (very probably), use `xev`

Comment: `KEY_MENU` is correct. Are you sure you don't have something assigned to that in your keyboard options?

Answer (score 1):

`KEY_COMPOSE` is the correct [Kernel keycode](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/include/uapi/linux/input-event-codes.h?h=v5.15.14#n204).

Some elaboration from [Chromium’s keyboard event notes](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/dff16958029d9a8fb9004351f72e961ed4143e83/ui/events/keycodes/dom/keycode_converter_data.inc):

> 'Menu' and 'Props' naming differs between evdev and USB / UI Events. USB 0x010085 [System Main Menu] and USB 0x0C0040 [Menu Mode] both map to evdev 0x8B KEY_MENU (which has no corresponding UI Events |code|). USB 0x070076 [Keyboard Menu] does not map to KEY_MENU; it maps to evdev 0x82 KEY_PROPS, which is not the same as USB and UI Events "Props". USB 0x0700A3 [Props], which does correspond to UI Events "Props", is not mapped by the kernel. (And all of these are distinct from UI Events' "ContextMenu", which corresponds to USB 0x070065 [Keyboard Application] via evdev 0x7F KEY_COMPOSE, following Windows convention.)